# Batch script to import excel sheet to mysql

Tags: mysql, powershell

I am new to Batch scripting. I am wondering whether can batch scripting allows to import excel sheets into mysql?

If it is possible, can someone provide me some help?

Comment: FTR, PowerShell and batch scripts are two entirely different things.

Answer (score 0):

You can read Excel files via Oledb or Excel COM interface.

Take a look at this [Scripting Guys' article](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2008/09/11/how-can-i-read-from-excel-without-using-excel.aspx). A brief copy-and-paste for the Oledb alternative:

```
$strFileName = "C:\Data\scriptingGuys\Servers.xls"
$strSheetName = 'ServerList$'
$strProvider = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0"
$strDataSource = "Data Source = $strFileName"
$strExtend = "Extended Properties=Excel 8.0"
$strQuery = "Select * from [$strSheetName]"

$objConn = New-Object System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("$strProvider;$strDataSource;$strExtend")
$sqlCommand = New-Object System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand($strQuery)
$sqlCommand.Connection = $objConn
$objConn.open()
$DataReader = $sqlCommand.ExecuteReader()

While($DataReader.read()) {
    # Insert data into MySql here
}  
$dataReader.close()
$objConn.close()
```

Powershell can connect into MySql [quite easily](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mysql/automate-mysql-queries-with-powershell.html) via .Net, if you have installed Mysql.Net connector.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I'm trying to digest your coding. If I'm not wrong, this is the batch scripting?

Btw, I can't access to your hyperlink **(Scripting Guys' article)**.

Comment: The code is PowerShell. Batch scripting means the old batch language that has its roots in MS-DOS, and is executed on cmd.exe shell.